# Does Hadoop have an overhead for systems with not so large dataflow?

Tags: hadoop, distributed-computing

I am planning to write a batch distributed computing system that will use about 10-20 computers. The data flow in certain parts of the system will be about ~50GB, and in other parts considerably smaller ~1GB.

I am thinking about using Hadoop. The scalability  is not important, but I really like the fault tolerance and speculative run features that Hadoop framewok offers. Frameworks like [MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/) or [gearman](http://gearman.org/) don't seem to provide such mechanisms, and I will have to implement them by myself.

However, I have some doubts because it seems to be optimized for larger data amounts and possibly more computers. For example, the book Hadoop the Definitive Guide mentions explicitly:

> The High Performance Computing (HPC) and Grid Computing communities have
>   been doing large-scale data processing for years, using such APIs as Message Passing
>   Interface (MPI). Broadly, the approach in HPC is to distribute the work across a cluster
>   of machines, which access a shared filesystem, hosted by a SAN. This works well for
>   predominantly compute-intensive jobs, but becomes a problem when nodes need to
>   access larger data volumes (hundreds of gigabytes, the point at which MapReduce really
>   starts to shine), since the network bandwidth is the bottleneck and compute nodes
>   become idle.

My questions are:

1. Does Hadoop have a considerable overhead when using it with relatively small amount of data and/or computers?
2. Is there another framework that provides fault-tolerance handling in any way close to Hadoop?

Comment: What are the latencies you're looking for? Hadoop is essentially a batch system (unlike,say, MPI that you mentioned)

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz, the system will be a batch system, not real-time or even close to it. Fault tolerance is currently more important than runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop will introduce overhead into your environment both form the operations perspective (new system which is still going through major development and changes); a cluster with multiple servers and disks that you have to maintain; etc as well computational overhead - "waking the elephant" so to speak, takes some time which is negligible if the job takes an hour but are noticeable if you expect a job to end under a minute.

Specifically 1GB and even 50GB is data that you can fit in memory these days, so a multi-threaded, single server solution can be much more effective for that...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is helpful. I forgot to mention in my question that I already have a cluster of computers, so probably I want to take advantage of it. Is there another framework that has fault tolerance like Hadoop?

Comment: There are several in-memory framework like datagrids (like gridgain, hazelcast, gigaspaces), there are actor based systems like Akka (or Erlang if you're not already too invested in JVM languages) and streaming frameworks like S4 or Storm. It all depends on your specific needs